# different python versions in anaconda and windows cmd , pip install not working

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, pip

I want windows command prompet to work on the same version anaconda prompet witch is 3.9

also I want windows command prompet to run and install pip packages like opencv-python

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With Anaconda you have conda for enviornment handling. Have a look at [conda enviornments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) and how to [install packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html) with conda.
In the Anaconda Prompt with Admin rights you can do:

```
conda create -n py39 python=3.9
activate py39
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Then you can use your new env in any command prompt with:

```
activate py39
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better to use:

- anaconda prompt

  In windows 10 search box search for `anaconda prompt`
- python virtual environment.

  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html